# Parse (string)table with parent tr´s into array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I have a string with a table inside; my problem is to put the parent tr´s (according their childs) into array (for later using it is not important whether array is one- or multidimensional)
The table looks like this:

```
<tr><td class="boys" colspan="4"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="indoor" colspan="4"></td></tr>
    <tr class="toy">
        <td class="article">Ball</td>
        <td class="color">Red</td>
        <td class="size">big</td>
        <td class="price">10</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="toy">
        <td class="article">Puzzle</td>
        <td class="color">colored</td>
        <td class="size">medium</td>
        <td class="price">5</td>
    </tr>       

<tr><td class="outdoor" colspan="4"></td></tr>
    <tr class="toy">
        <td class="article">Inliner</td>
        <td class="color">black</td>
        <td class="size">5</td>
        <td class="price">15</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="toy">
        <td class="article">Pool</td>
        <td class="color">white/blue</td>
        <td class="size">big</td>
        <td class="price">25</td>
    </tr>   

<tr><td class="all" colspan="4"></td></tr>
    <tr class="toy">
        <td class="article">Book</td>
        <td class="color">colored</td>
        <td class="size">small</td>
        <td class="price">2</td>
    </tr>
```

and same tr/td construct for girls.

With

```
$html = str_get_html($e);

$toys= array();
foreach ( $html->find('tr[class=toy]') as $toy) {
 $item['article'] = trim($toys->find('td', 0)->plaintext);
 $item['color'] = trim($toys->find('td', 1)->plaintext);
 $item['size'] = trim($toys->find('td', 2)->plaintext);
 $item['price'] = trim($toys->find('td', 3)->plaintext);
 $toys[] = $item;
}
```

How can i get both parents? So that array looks like

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [sex] => boys
        [place] => indoor
        [article] => Puzzle
        [color] => colored
        [size] => medium
        [price] => 5
    )
```

trying to get it with

```
$item['place'] = $toys->find('tr.toy', 0)->plaintext;
```

give wrong results...

Comment: Isn't it `$item['article'] = trim($toy->find('td', 0)->plaintext);` ?

Comment: `$toy` vs `$toys` typo

Comment: also wouldn't `place` be the class of the child of previous row to the row with a class of `toys`: `$toys->prev_sibling ()->find('td', 0)->class`

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with js or jquery, perhaps you should remove those tags and add that you are using php simple dom parser (if that is what you are using), it was the first result when I did a search for `str_get_html`

Comment: the way to get the array - can be done in php, jquery or whatever - main issue is the right array ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted the complete table structure (for girls as well), so I assume it looks like this:

```
<table id="products">
    <tr><td class="boys" colspan="4"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="indoor" colspan="4"></td></tr>
    <tr class="toy">...</tr>

    <tr><td class="outdoor" colspan="4"></td></tr>
    <tr class="toy">...</tr>

    <tr><td class="girls" colspan="4"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="indoor" colspan="4"></td></tr>
    <tr class="toy">...</tr>

    <tr><td class="outdoor" colspan="4"></td></tr>
    <tr class="toy">...</tr>
</table>
```

As I wanted to familiarize with the Simple DOM Parser Package, this was a welcome exercise for me. I leave the code as is. I hope it isn't against SO-Rules to omit explanations. So if an angry admin disagrees, or the OP wants some additional info, leave another answer here and I'll provide it in the future. Please regard the table-attribute id.

```
$ret = $html->find("table[id=products] tr");
$items = array();
$item = NULL;

foreach($ret as $r)
{
    echo "got in the loop<br>";

    $class = $r->getAttribute("class");

    echo "class: $class<br>";

    if (strlen(trim($class)) == 0)
    {
        echo "We have a <tr> without a class<br>";
        $td = $r->firstChild();
        $class = $td->getAttribute("class");

        echo "The &lt;td&gt;-child should either have class boys,girls, indoor or outdoor<br>";

        if (strcasecmp($class, "girls") == 0 ||
            strcasecmp($class, "boys") == 0)
        {
            $sex = $class;
            echo "It's a $sex<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            if (strcasecmp($class, "indoor") == 0 ||
                strcasecmp($class, "outdoor") == 0)
            {
                $place = $class;
                echo "Item is meant for $place-usage<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $childs = $r->childNodes();
        $item = array();
        $item["place"] = $place;
        $item["sex"] = $sex;

        echo "Creating new item for $place-$sex<br>";

        foreach($childs as $child)
        {
            $class = $child->getAttribute("class");
            $item[$class] = $child->innertext;
            echo "Item attribute $class with ".$child->innertext."<br>";
        }
        array_push($items, $item);
     }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($items);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Take a close look at the <table>-tag. I added an id-attribute for this to work. At least it works as expected in my test-environment. Please verify, that the table-structure I gave in my answer, is similar to yours.

Comment: i added the id, too - but get an empty array. I use simple_html_dom.php.

Comment: That's unpleasant for sure. My first approach would be to check if $html was initialized. Is your initial $html = str_get_html($e); still present? If yes, do you use the latest version of PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser (although I think this isn't the reason)? Then you could try print simple debugging output. I made the relevant changes within my original-answer. I don't know if my own code needs to be approved by the SO-Admins, therefore you may see it, when approved by them.

Comment: sorry, my mistake - haven´t add the class to toys.
Works perfect, thanks!